# How to enable mount network disk in elfinder laravel for google drive

Tags: php, laravel-5, elfinder

I have question of elfinder, how to enable 'Mount Network Disk' on elfinder for use google drive in laravel 5.2. Could tell you me, which are steps to follow.

The steps i followed were:

Installation with composer.

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-elfinder
```

Add the ServiceProvider to the providers array in app/config/app.php

```
Barryvdh\Elfinder\ElfinderServiceProvider::class
```

Copy the assets to the public folder, using the following artisan command:

```
php artisan elfinder:publish
```

Run command.

```
composer update
```

I used the default configuration, I created the folder 'files' in the public folder. 
With the command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider='Barryvdh\Elfinder\ElfinderServiceProvider' --tag=config
```

and

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider='Barryvdh\Elfinder\ElfinderServiceProvider' --tag=views
```

In the file elfinder.php with the route

```
'vendor/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder/config/elfinder.php'
```

In the section route use

```
'route' => [
    'prefix' => 'elfinder',
    'middleware' => null, //Set to null to disable middleware filter
     ]
```

In the file filesystems.php with the route

```
'/config/filesystems.php'.
```

In the section disk in the option public, add the line

```
'root' => base_path().'app/public',
```

after of the line

```
'driver' => 'local',
```

Example:

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => base_path().'app/public',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => 'your-key',
        'secret' => 'your-secret',
        'region' => 'your-region',
        'bucket' => 'your-bucket',
    ],

],
```

This is how i solved the error that occurs when you use the copy option, open folder, etc.

```
Error, Unable to connect to backend. HTTP error 0
```

But I do not know, what is needed to use the mount network disk.And
how to give the folder(example: Reading)

This is link of the project
https://github.com/AlonsoCauich/driveOne